# How can I prevent the_post_thumbnail() overflow?

Tags: wordpress, overflow

I don't want set this

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );
```

because it output me a fixed size image, but I want obtain max image size, obviously with correct aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( "full" ); ?>
```

In addition to specifying a size, there are also multiple keywords such as "thumbnail", "medium", "large" and "full" which get you different premade sizes. You can also register your own image size using

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

Then every time you upload an image it will crop to that size as well